# UTF-8 not working with Cyrillic text from raw folder

Tags: java, android

I have a text file in the res/raw folder in cyrilic.

```
InputStream ints = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.h9);
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.h1), "UTF8"));

while (( line = input.readLine())  )
{
...
}
```

yet when I try to read it line by line in "UTF8", it gives me strange characters.

any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the other UTFs? Maybe you're mistaken about how the file is encoded.

Comment: you mean utf-16 , doesn't work either. are there any more utfs?

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaken about how the file is encoded.

Answer (score -1):

got it, it was encoded in **CP-1251** !